# Facebook Developer - Unnamed App

Tags: facebook

I setup a facebook app for my client's website like I've done many many times before, but now for some reason each of the apps I create have a duplicate app called 'Unnamed App'.

At the moment I can't delete them, and when I try to load the delete URL directly, it just says 'Please try again later.' I used to be able to delete them, perhaps its just a temporary thing, but REGARDLESS, **these unnamed apps just keep popping up again and again even after I delete them.**

Anyone experienced this before or know what to do to fix it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. I've filed an internal bug report. I'll post when I have an update. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Oh why thank you :) I'll keep track of this to see what happens :)